# Connecting a terminal based node.js app to a socket.io server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am able to connect a web based app to a socket.io server, but not a terminal based app, this is what i use to connect to the socket.io server:

```
var socket = require('socket.io')
var connection = socket.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
```

I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: socket.connect is not a function
```

How can I connect a terminal app to a socket.io server, written in node.js

Comment: why are you using `socket` before importing it?

Comment: I've tried it both ways round:

Comment: Try the browser client?

Comment: I do not want to use a browser, its a terminal based application I wan't to connect to my socket.io server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `socket.io` is for creating WebSocket server. You can't use this module as a client. Instead try [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)

```
  var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
  socket.on('connect', function(){});
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```